# 1 or 2 independent variables,18 dependent variables

Tags: categorical-data, nonparametric

I am having trouble selecting the right statistical analysis to answer my question. I have 1 categorical (two-levels) predictor, 1 categorical (two-level) independent variable that I would like to control for, and 18 dependent, continious variables. I need to find out which of the dependent variables are significantly different as a result of the predictor. The data meet the assumptions of normality and homogeneity of variance.

A MANOVA does not provide me with enough information, as I really need to single out the dependent variables. Otherwise, I suppose I could perform 18 t-tests, and correct to minimize the type-I error, but that does not seem very elegant. Is there perhaps a test that I have overlooked?

Thanks in advance!

*

> 4 groups of mice have been trained in a learning paradigm during
>   either 3 sessions (2 groups) or 5 sessions (2 groups). In both
>   condition of training duration, some animals were "sham operated" (SH)
>   and some other were lesioned in the dorsal hippocampus (H).n1 hr after
>   the last session, mice were sacrificed and the number of zif
>   immunopositive cells per surface unit was counted in 19 structures. In
>   these conditions, we can consider that this measure reflects the
>   activity of the structure during the last session of the task.
>   - Which are the structures that are differentially activated depending on the duration of training ?

*

Comment: The cell counts most likely do not meet assumptions of normality. They will probably be Poisson or quasi-Poisson distributed. How are you determining the assumption is met? (Also, different analyses here will have different assumptions of normality)

Comment: According to the shapiro.test() function, 13 out of 17 cells are normally distributed...

Comment: The test does *not* tell you if the distribution is normal. Check questions on here that address assessing normality.